# Criteria for the bound of an operator acting on an infinite dimensional Hilbert space

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, separable-spaces

Consider a linear Hermitian operator acting on a finite dimensional vector space. This operator is bounded, and in order to find the bound I am calculating the largest eigenvalue in its matrix representation.

Now if my vector space is an infinite dimensional and continuous Hilbert space (a non-separable Hilbert space, say $l^2(\mathbb{R})$), do I have any similar notion of "largest eigenvalue" of the operator? Or is there another way to determine the bound of this operator?

Note: I have a physics background, would appreciate some examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a selfadjoint bounded operator $T$ on a Hilbert space, you always have
$$
\|T\|=\max\{|\lambda|:\ \lambda\in \sigma(T)\},
$$
where $\sigma(T)$ is the spectrum
$$
\sigma(T)=\{\lambda:\ T-\lambda I\ \text{ is not invertible}\}. 
$$
The equality holds more generally when $T$ is normal ($T^*T=TT^*$) but fails in general: for example $T=\begin{bmatrix} 0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ has $\|T\|=1$ but $\sigma(T)=\{0\}$.

You cannot do the above with eigenvalues, as these may fail to exist. For example let $H=L^2[0,1]$, and $T$ the multiplication operator
$$
(Tf)(x)=xf(x). 
$$
Then $\|T\|=1$ and $\sigma(T)=[0,1]$, but $T$ has no eigenvalues.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you are right $T$ defined on $L^2[0,1]$ does not have any notion of eigenvalues. A query, how do I ensure $T - \lambda I$ is not invertible? For countable cases, we can write the characteristic polynomial, which can be used to determine the maximum of the spectrum. Say I have $T$ defined on $L^2[\mathbb{R}]$, is there a convenient way to determine the maximum of the spectrum?

Comment: There is no general method. It depends heavily on how the operator is presented, and it might be crazy hard to do.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.